# SSL Secure login but non secure resources, does this make sense?

Tags: security, session, authentication, ssl, https

We have a website, which uses SSL for Login/Signup since we have a limitation on using SSL.
so after login it goes to another non secure site and uses a radnom generated session token to identify user transactions.

How secure is that? considering that if any sniffer caught the token while the actual user is browsing can use it for malicious actions.

Any other ideas to secure user's session?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you have your answer right in your question. The users login credentials are protected, but anyone can take over the user's active session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using session tokens to maintain active sessions (a standard and well-established practice) over HTTP, you are vulnerable to session hijacking, where anyone that can intercept a valid traffic flow can grab that token and reuse it.

If you want to prevent this, you need to conduct all of your interactions with the user over SSL/TLS, as then the token will only be sent over the encrypted tunnnel.

If you cannot do so, then you're vulnerable. You can introduce some level of mitigation to this risk by doing things like associating a session token with an IP address (only accept a session token if it is presented by the same client IP address that it was issued it), but then you're opening up a can of worms as IP addresses can change (imagine a user logged in to your site and then moving wireless networks, for example).

You need to ask if this threat is significant enough for you to address. What type of data is being processed by your application? If it is sensitive, then you probably need to protect it...if it's public and you're just using user logins to keep track of who is accessing what, then perhaps you don't That all depends on your risk analysis.

There are a few other ideas on the [OWASP Session Management webpage](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management)...but if you truly need to address this threat, then you need to conduct all of your interactions over SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 2):

Punch [`Firesheep`](http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep/tc12/#1) into your favorite search engine and it will soon become obvious that's not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I know this firefox plugin... but I can't imagine that there's no solution other than SSL.

Comment: There are other solutions, they just tend to be much worse. You could do everything using AJAX and use any form of encryption you want.

Answer (score 1):

This subject has been documented at great length on the IT Security stack exchange:

- [What sites are still vulnerable to FireSheep?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11631/971)  Answer: any site that is not using SSL sitewide -- sites that use your proposed approach (SSL only for the login form, no SSL thereafter) are vulnerable.
- [Can you secure a web app from FireSheep without using SSL?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1322/971)  Short answer: no.  Long answer: in theory yes, but in practice, not so much.  The alternatives all suck worse.
- [What are the pros and cons of site wide SSL (https)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/258/971)  Pros: you're not vulnerable any longer.

And finally, a bonus: details on how to protect yourself from this threat:

- [How to Deploy HTTPS Correctly](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/deploying-https)
- [Guidance for implementors of HTTPS-only sites (Server side)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7790/971)

Comment: that was a great detailed short answer with references :)

Comment: Thanks, @BasselAlkhateeb!  Glad it helped.  Feel free to upvote it if you think it was helpful.